# How to create a stored procedure that have CASE function in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure that has `CASE` function in the `WHERE` clause.

I have three tables: `Bank`, `Employee`, and `Level`.

I have one parameter `@BankName`, when `@BankName Like 'AB%'` then the result are employees that works for that bank.

When `@BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%'` then the result shown all the employee that work for other banks rather than bank AB.

When `@BankName IS NULL`, then it will shown all the results.

I've tried this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_EmpList]
    @BankNAME   VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        b.BankName,
        e.EmployeeName,
        l.LevelName
    FROM 
        Bank b 
    INNER JOIN 
        Employee e ON b.EmpID = e.EmpID
    INNER JOIN 
        Level l ON l.LvlID = e.LvlID
    WHERE
        b.BankName = CASE
                WHEN @BankName = 'AB' THEN 'AB'
                WHEN @BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%' THEN '' --This is where I'm confused.
                ELSE NULL
                 END
END
```

So, how can I get the result that I want? Or maybe there's a better syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `CASE` expression, use a combination of `AND`-`OR` conditions:

```
WHERE
    (@BankName IS NOT NULL AND @BankName LIKE 'AB%' AND b.BankName LIKE 'AB%')
    OR (@BankName IS NOT NULL AND @BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%' AND b.BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%')
    OR (@BankName IS NULL)
```

Note:

This type of query is called [catch-all-query.](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) There are a number of ways to implement this. One of which is the above. Read the article for more information.

Comment: Thank, that was too fast. :D

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the CASE with simple AND and OR clauses. Here is what that could look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_EmpList]
 @BankNAME  VARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        b.BankName,
        e.EmployeeName,
        l.LevelName
    FROM 
        Bank b INNER JOIN Employee e ON b.EmpID = e.EmpID
        INNER JOIN Level l ON l.LvlID = e.LvlID
    WHERE
        (@BankName = 'AB' AND b.BankName = 'AB') OR 
        (@BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%' AND b.BankName = '') OR
        (
          NOT (@BankName = 'AB' AND @BankName NOT LIKE 'AB%') AND
          b.bankName IS NULL
        )
```